# How do I view the transformed web.config while debugging (SlowCheetah)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, visual-studio-debugging, web-config-transform, slowcheetah

I've installed the `SlowCheetah plugin in VS 2010`. I can *Preview Transform* on `web.debug.config` and it looks correct. However I don't think the transform is occurring while debugging.

How do I view the transformed `web.config` while debugging?

Sorry if this has already been asked but I couldn't find instructions for specifically viewing the file.

Comment: [Indeed](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). Didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlowCheetah doesn't support it yet but its on the backlog http://slowcheetah.uservoice.com/forums/185106-general/suggestions/3385389-support-for-transforming-web-config-on-f5. Its the next feature that I'll work on.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Web.config transforms are only applied during the Web Publish Pipleline (WPP) that is on Publish, not during debug, to enable them during debug check the following link: http://sedodream.com/2010/10/21/ASPNETWebProjectsWebdebugconfigWebreleaseconfig.aspx .